# Как посчитать количество дубликатов каждого элемента массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Нужно выводить количество дубликатов каждого элемента массива, сначала сортируем, а затем говорим что если этот элемент равен следующему значит считаем ++

```js
function d(arr) {
  const array = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  let c = 0;
  return array.map((arr, i) => arr == arr[i + 1] ? c++ : 1)
}
```

Comment: Привидите пример входных данных и результата.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [структурами данных Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const countDup = dups => {
  const map = new Map()

  for (const dup of dups) {
    map.set(dup, map.get(dup) + 1 || 1)
  }
  return map
}

const result = countDup([1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 10, 3])

console.log(result)
// Map { 1 => 2, 2 => 1, 3 => 2, 7 => 1, 10 => 1 }
// в сниппете map не отображается

console.log(Array.from(result))
// [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 10, 1 ] ]

console.log(Object.fromEntries(result))
// {
//  "1": 2,
//  "2": 1,
//  "3": 2,
//  "7": 1,
//  "10": 1
// }
```

Comment: я хочу без обьекта ))

Comment: массиве - выше описал

Comment: @babakov.roman678 в ответе приведен пример с выводом в массив, с ним что то не так?

Comment: хотите помочь - сделайте по моему алгоритму

Comment: @babakov.roman678 зачем мне делать по Вашему "алгоритму"? У Вас пока его нет. А в вопросе Вы не добавили формат вывода